# Wordpress - Display "Custom Author Role Name" - WP Members Plugin Installed

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to display the custom author name than I created with WP_Members Plugin. I used this function inside function.php of my theme.

```
function get_author_role_name(){
    $role = get_the_author_meta('roles')['0'];
    echo esc_html($role);
}
```

It works fine, but it displays the "slug" of the role. I would like to display the name!

Ex. Name: "My Custom Role", the function displays "my-custom-role".

So, I could replace "-" with a space " " and I could use ucwords() function, but, is there a function to get the real name directly? I can't find it!

Thanks

**EDIT - SOLUTION HERE:**

```
function get_author_role_name(){
    $get_role = get_the_author_meta('roles')['0'];
    global $wp_roles;
    $role = $wp_roles->roles[$get_role]['name'];
    echo esc_html($role);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on above link, I edited my function like so:

```
function get_author_role_name(){
    $get_role = get_the_author_meta('roles')['0'];
    global $wp_roles;
    $role = $wp_roles->roles[$get_role]['name'];
    echo esc_html($role);
}
```